# strange behaviour by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have the following .htaccess file for me web

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-offers.html$   current-offers.php?id=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*).html$   vpn-offer-detail.php?id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-details.html$   vpn-provider-detail.php?id=$2 [L]
```

I was actually trying to implement SEO freindly URLs through htaccess file. When I uploaded the file in my web directory, I stuck in something strange.

It looks like that rewrite rule 1 (for offers) is okay, Condition 2 is okay too,

But, coming to condition 3, (vpn provider detail.php), a mess is happening.. the browser shows url correctly, but the page content shown are of not vpn provider.php. rather, the contents are being displayed of condition one (current offers.php) . I can't understand that why this is happening there. Note that URl is displayed in browser as it should be, but the contents of the page are of current_offers.php (redirecting to it, but not showing the the contents)

Can somebody Guide me please? and tell me what is the problem with my code? or why this is happening to me?

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question of order.

*Hide-My-Ass-1009-details.html* doesn't pass the 1st condition, but pass the 2nd one and with [L] - which means Last - it goes for this one.

A fast solution should be

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-offers.html$   current-offers.php?id=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-details.html$   vpn-provider-detail.php?id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*).html$   vpn-offer-detail.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the guideline bro. can you please tell me the logic behind the order in which conditions appear..this might look a studpid question but I am really thinking about it. The redirect will only happen when a conidtion is met, so why order is important?

Comment: As you said, it redirects when a condition is met. The RewriteEngine reads it normally (up to bottom). With your original one and with *Hide-My-Ass-1009-details.html*, it reads the 1st regex and sees it doesn't work. Then, it goes to the 2nd one (`^(.*)-(.*).html$`)and sees it works. It reads *[L]*, so it doesn't read anymore rule for this request. So, it takes the 2nd one to redirect. Your conditions (with [L] and all) could be read if-elseif-else.